# How can I re-install the system Ruby on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, libraries, homebrew

I installed Homebrew and it recommended that I delete the following "***evil***" libraries:

```
libcvP11.dylib
libcvP11LCB.dylib
libfuse.2.dylib
libfuse_ino64.2.dylib
libgcc_s.1.dylib
libgcc_s.10.4.dylib
libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
libgfortran.2.0.0.dylib
libhistory.6.1.dylib
libreadline.6.1.dylib
libruby.1.9.1.dylib
libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
libtcl8.4.dylib
libtk8.4.dylib
```

So, I went ahead and rm'ed all the files.

Now, when I type `Ruby -v`, I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local//lib/libruby.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ruby
Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 1.9.1 or later, but
libruby.dylib provides version 1.8.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I believe the system Ruby is now complaining that it cannot find `libruby.1.9.1.dylib`!

In the mean time, I have successfully installed Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM, but I'd still like my system Ruby not to be corrupt. I'm considering re-installing the complete system Ruby, but I'm open to all suggestions. I'm also worried that other apps may be broken because of the files I have deleted. I would appreciate any help as to what I should do next.

I don't know what dynamic libraries are and what they are used for, but I'm under the impression that the files I deleted weren't so evil after all!

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete

Comment: Worked wonderfully! Thank you, Dave. I would nevertheless be interested to understand why the above dynamic libraries were termed "evil" according to homebrew and if it would be necessary to recover them somehow.

Comment: Perhaps because `brew` will install its own versions? Not sure :)

Comment: Homebrew describes them as "evil" since they could conflict with homebrew-installed libraries. I recommend completely removing all MacPorts-installed libraries & re-installing anything you need with homebrew. https://gist.github.com/986553

Comment: I recommend using RVM to manage non-Apple install Rubies over Homebrew or MacPorts, but that's my choice of poison. The bigger issue is you should not use a mix of the various ways of installing software. Determine which is best for your needs and do not jump back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

RVM is definitely the way to go. You should install all your ruby versions through it and if possible create a different [gemset](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) for each project. It will really help you in not getting any kind of conflicts.